# Split string against some characters except the # character

Tags: java

I want to split a string against the following characters

`~!@$%^&*()_+­=<>,.?/:;"'{}|[]\, \n,\t, space`

I tried to use `\\s` regex delimiter but i don't want the `#` included as the split character so that a string like `this is #funny` should result to `this` `is` `#funny` as the resulting values.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

`this is #funny".split("\\s")`

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: How about `"this is #funny".split("\\s|#")` ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow.  We're generally very happy to help, but you're going to have to help us do that.   You'll want to post some code showing the problem, and what you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: `\\s` is for whitespace only. How does this match your requirement of all the other characters?

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the characters you want in square bracket, which means *any of*. Single escape Java characters (like `\"`) and double escape Regex special characters (like `\\[`):

```
@Test
public void testName() throws Exception
{
    String[] split = "this is #funny".split("[~!@$%^&*()_+­=<>,.?/:;\"'{}|\\[\\]\\\\ \\n\\t]");
    for (String string : split) 
    {
        logger.debug(string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User replaceAll(String regex,String replacement) method from String.

```
 String result = "this is #funny".replaceAll("[~!@$%^&*()_+­=<>,.?/:;\"'{}|\\[\\]\\,\\n\\t]", "");
 System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like this will work for you:

```
String[] split = str.split("[^a-zA-Z&&[^#]]+");
```

This uses a character class *subtraction* to split on non-letter chars, except the hash.

---

Here's some test code:

```
String str = "this is #funny";
String[] split = str.split("[^a-zA-Z&&[^#]]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

Output:

```
[this, is, #funny]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement this:

```
String[] split = "this&is%a#funny^string".split("[^#\\p{Alnum}]|\\s+");
for (String string : split){
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Also check the [Java API (Patterns)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more information on how to process strings.